# Inconsistent Response When Using Axios (Postman vs VSCode)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, axios

Good Evening,
I'm building Azure functions using VSCode and am running into issues where Axios retrieves only part of a payload from the designated endpoint. I have verified that I'm using the same bearer token which means the same permissions are applied.

Currently running the following:

- Node.js 14.16.0
- Axios 0.21.3 (downgraded from 0.21.4 due to this same
  issue)

VS Code Example (The code works as far as authentication, making calls & receiving data):

```
const config = {
    method: "get",
    url: `${process.env.procore_BaseURL}/rest/v1.0/projects/${req.body.project_id}/users?filters[employee]=true`,
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${req.body.procore_token}` },
    withCredentials: true,
  };

  const { data: userList } = await axios(config);
```

In response, I get an array of 9 objects that contain two key-value pairs and one compound object (I provided a subset of the response for brevity).

```
[
  { "id": 945366,
    "name": "Neil L..",
    "vendor": {
      "id": 2374952,
      "name": "K...A, INC."
    }
  }
]
```

What I should be receiving, is an object that contains the following key-value pairs:

```
[
  {
    "address": "6305 Carpinteria Ave",
    "avatar": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/pro-core.com/prostore/20150713184222_production_74548228.gif?AWSAccessKeyId=0PFNH01C4MZVXKXZNK82&Expires=2067964943&Signature=l4zpZIM3bgxydrr4hn6lM%2FdtreQ%3D",
    "business_phone": "1234567890",
    "business_phone_extension": "21",
    "city": "Carpinteria",
    "country_code": "US",
    "email_address": "jane.doe@example.com",
    "email_signature": "<p>Sent from Procore.</p>",
    "employee_id": "123456789",
    "erp_integrated_accountant": true,
    "fax_number": "5555555555",
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "id": 381006,
    "initials": "JD",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_employee": true,
    "job_title": "QA Manager",
    "last_login_at": "2016-06-30T20:41:58Z",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "mobile_phone": "5555555555",
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "notes": "notes",
    "state_code": "CA",
    "welcome_email_sent_at": "2013-05-30T20:41:58Z",
    "zip": "93013",
    "origin_id": "foobar",
    "origin_data": "OD-2398273424",
    "created_at": "2016-10-23T21:39:40Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-23T21:39:40Z",
    "vendor": {
      "id": 161072,
      "name": "SID Architecture"
    },
    "default_permission_template_id": 27,
    "work_classification_id": 13,
    "permission_template": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "General Contractor",
      "project_specific": true,
      "type": "global"
    }
  }
]
```

When I make a call to the same endpoint using Postman, using the same bearer token, I do get the complete response payload. I'm absolutely puzzled by this as it just started behaving like this in the past few days. I don't recall making any changes in my code that would cause this behavior.

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**9/13/2021 EDIT**

Below is the request header from within the debugging tool in VSCode.

```
{
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:7071/api/procore_ProjectUsers",
  originalUrl: "http://localhost:7071/api/procore_ProjectUsers",
  headers: {
    connection: "close",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    host: "localhost:7071",
    "user-agent": "axios/0.21.3",
    "content-length": "2672",
  },
  query: {
  },
  params: {
  },
  body: {
    api_version: "v2",
    company_id: 4923,
    event_type: "update",
    id: 2321321,
    metadata: {
      source_application_id: null,
      source_company_id: 4923,
      source_operation_id: null,
      source_project_id: 1466740,
      source_user_id: 945366,
    },
    project_id: 448081,
    resource_id: 945366,
    resource_name: "Project Users",
    timestamp: "2021-05-21",
    ulid: "fljasdflk",
    user_id: 945366,
    procore_token: "eyJh...KrrC",
    display_name: "50-21509 - LEARNING CENTER [TEST PROJECT]",
    projectNumber: "50-21509",
  }
}
```

Below is the entire response from within VSCode

```
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: {
    date: 'Mon, 13 Sep 2021 15:44:32 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
    connection: 'close',
    'set-cookie': [
      'AWSALB=riudyffAEgU6n4aa50aBKwrVsNF3+KJq8Jx7mlxOHvuis58w6iIobfFL+ieFT7qcF/kxIwy/fRzqDYSuNAMzex4K0geX8JksWJ7yEt1Y7YA8eL+kqf/hZN6pIwGk; Expires=Mon, 20 Sep 2021 15:44:31 GMT; Path=/',
      'AWSALBCORS=riudyffAEgU6n4aa50aBKwrVsNF3+KJq8Jx7mlxOHvuis58w6iIobfFL+ieFT7qcF/kxIwy/fRzqDYSuNAMzex4K0geX8JksWJ7yEt1Y7YA8eL+kqf/hZN6pIwGk; Expires=Mon, 20 Sep 2021 15:44:31 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure',
      'AWSALBTG=i1ZenVNnmsAzlmpexwWJvQhwdrjxgOUmIRKru5o83ahIsNA4+6JbcTg7W6ty+X9tmwT4U8mHNzjQn8t3qsF4pJuSp0RFSe8Yb7pN2ivyDDq6fi1MIuEK4TDFN5jLcWE7qy08XoZjsjdE0aU2g6imQ5p656nlKmXrEIdy9PTMOEQvH23l+BE=; Expires=Mon, 20 Sep 2021 15:44:31 GMT; Path=/',
      'AWSALBTGCORS=i1ZenVNnmsAzlmpexwWJvQhwdrjxgOUmIRKru5o83ahIsNA4+6JbcTg7W6ty+X9tmwT4U8mHNzjQn8t3qsF4pJuSp0RFSe8Yb7pN2ivyDDq6fi1MIuEK4TDFN5jLcWE7qy08XoZjsjdE0aU2g6imQ5p656nlKmXrEIdy9PTMOEQvH23l+BE=; Expires=Mon, 20 Sep 2021 15:44:31 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure'
    ],
    'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    'per-page': '10000',
    total: '9',
    'x-rate-limit-limit': '3600',
    'x-rate-limit-remaining': '3574',
    'x-rate-limit-reset': '1631549044',
    etag: 'W/"0640594046722873fa6676187fb04229"',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0, private, must-revalidate',
    'x-request-id': '8f90ba76-abd3-45dc-85fa-4bef8b8d15e0',
    'x-runtime': '0.555740',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains',
    'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '803',
    server: 'envoy'
  },
  config: {
    url: 'https://api.procore.com/rest/v1.0/projects/448081/users?filters[employee]=true',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      Authorization: 'Bearer eyJh...7ik5',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.3'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    data: undefined
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: 0,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.procore.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.procore.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 220,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: 'GET /rest/v1.0/projects/448081/users?filters[employee]=true HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Bearer eyJh...R7ik5\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.21.3\r\n' +
      'Host: api.procore.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'fifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'GET',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/rest/v1.0/projects/448081/users?filters[employee]=true',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 200,
      statusMessage: 'OK',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: true,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.procore.com/rest/v1.0/projects/448081/users?filters[employee]=true',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'api.procore.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 0,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.procore.com/rest/v1.0/projects/448081/users?filters[employee]=true',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      authorization: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  data: [
    { id: 945366, name: 'Neil L...', vendor: [Object] },
    { id: 1012129, name: 'John E...', vendor: [Object] },
    { id: 3607712, name: 'Jessica F...', vendor: [Object] },
    { id: 5961345, name: 'Chris W...', vendor: [Object] },
    { id: 6684024, name: 'Harrold S...', vendor: [Object] },
    { id: 6863821, name: 'Brittany M...', vendor: [Object] },
    { id: 7196952, name: 'Todd H...', vendor: [Object] },
    { id: 7202959, name: 'Hajime Y...', vendor: [Object] },
    { id: 7285171, name: 'Heidi H...', vendor: [Object] }
  ]
}
```

I received an incomplete response once again, however, I ran it first thing this morning and DID receive a complete response. It's as if there is something in the cache preventing me from retrieving everything. This occurs regardless of using VSCode in debugging mode OR MS Azure Portal (Running Azure Functions).

Conversely, in Postman, I consistently receive the full response payload. Those response headers are below.

```
{
  Date: 'Mon, 13 Sep 2021 15:53:52 GMT',
  Content-Type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  Transfer-Encoding: 'chunked',
  Connection: 'keep-alive',
  'Set-Cookie': 
'AWSALB=BjhLK8sqAGMkb7eBG9u9TYPJus4mcmez9n8ZqKfA1pCAGCrco98jXRreiD9M0wWsJDh+0+i7CBNPF+c3cuY5dxKo+MM58bvHc+lgsPz4FgHet5VvafYQI5kcx1Ox; Expires=Mon, 20 Sep 2021 15:53:51 GMT; Path=/',
'Set-Cookie': 'AWSALBCORS=BjhLK8sqAGMkb7eBG9u9TYPJus4mcmez9n8ZqKfA1pCAGCrco98jXRreiD9M0wWsJDh+0+i7CBNPF+c3cuY5dxKo+MM58bvHc+lgsPz4FgHet5VvafYQI5kcx1Ox; Expires=Mon, 20 Sep 2021 15:53:51 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure'
'set-cookie': 'AWSALBTG=IbjihMjCYqfo6yTeRrQrDfkVjE7h2ajv2RpVmfvLsq1Fvlx8v9GslcvF25tIfBW3zJtAoutX4n6W2qKiGaR078CQAiRNHXxxjHnUQNwJLjGn25V/v5elj48RSY55X1QvK122/p5XAdt30bdKpLSZaThnl0/EEd79O68uMJmbEqmnh9VDH2E=; Expires=Mon, 20 Sep 2021 15:53:51 GMT; Path=/'
'set-cookie': 'AWSALBTGCORS=IbjihMjCYqfo6yTeRrQrDfkVjE7h2ajv2RpVmfvLsq1Fvlx8v9GslcvF25tIfBW3zJtAoutX4n6W2qKiGaR078CQAiRNHXxxjHnUQNwJLjGn25V/v5elj48RSY55X1QvK122/p5XAdt30bdKpLSZaThnl0/EEd79O68uMJmbEqmnh9VDH2E=; Expires=Mon, 20 Sep 2021 15:53:51 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure'
x-frame-options: 'SAMEORIGIN'.
x-xss-protection: '1; mode=block',
x-content-type-options: 'nosniff',
per-page: 10000
total: 9
x-rate-limit-limit: 3600
x-rate-limit-remaining: 3599
x-rate-limit-reset: 1631552031
etag: 'W/"cb0fb243bddd497ca0dcd06d95a6285b"',
cache-control: 'max-age=0, private, must-revalidate',
x-request-id: '17f44326-ec1b-47d9-8005-5d91f2ea4588',
x-runtime: 1.233074
strict-transport-security: 'max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains',
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1241
server: 'envoy',
vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
content-encoding: 'gzip'
}
```

Admittedly, I'm not an expert, but I can't see anything that jumps out as overtly wrong. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: If auth were the problem, you'd be more apt to see an error, not a partial response.  I'd aim my suspicion toward a race condition on the server, like the connection getting closed before the result is fully sent.

Answer (score 2):

After sitting down with an engineer at the software vendor, it was found that the token was being issued, but the software wasn't retrieving it entirely. I copied/pasted the key and secret into the platform again and it started working.

Lesson Learned - Ensure that the keys, secrets and tokens are 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

As Dan pointed out in the comment, it's probably got nothing to do with auth. Though I don't think it could be a problem with the connection getting closed, since the json object *is* readable, therefore it's sending partial information for a different reason.

Can you update your question with at least some of the server code and the headers in the requests.

In my experience, axios is funny with the way it sets headers, so you should check the difference in headers between postman and axios.

My suggestion right now is to try the same request using the **fetch api**.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, I doubt this has much to do with axios, instead it's probably whatever server you're sending the request to; so, check your code on the server, and try to find a difference between the requests from axios and postman, that's the best help I can offer.

Also, are you parsing the results as json? Try doing so like this

```
const { data: userList } = await axios(config).json();
```

Comment: I'll try test your answer